# Avoiding numerical instability when computing 1/(1+exp(x)) python

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, scipy, expansion

I would like to compute 1/(1+exp(x))  for (possibly large) x. This is a well behaved function between 0 and 1. I could just do

```
import numpy as np
1.0/(1.0+np.exp(x))
```

but in this naive implementation np.exp(x) will likely just return 0 or infinity for large x, depending on the sign. Are there functions available in python that will help me out here?

I am considering implementing a series expansion and series acceleration, but I am wondering if this problem has already been solved.

Comment: Can you give examples of inputs for which you get poor outputs, alongside the outputs that you'd like to get for those inputs? The expression you give is actually fairly well-behaved numerically for almost all `x`. (The only difficult area I can think of is where `np.exp(x)` only just overflows a double, where you'll end up getting zero instead of the correct subnormal value.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`scipy.special.expit(-x)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.expit.html).  It will avoid the overflow warnings generated by `1.0/(1.0 + exp(x))`.

Comment: Nice - `expit` also works with `np.longdouble`, and overflows at slightly larger values of `x` than my naive answer.

Comment: @ali_m Thanks for checking that.  I removed "still 64 bit floating point" from the answer.

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware of the existence of `scipy.special.expit(-x)`. Great find!

Answer (score 2):

Fundamentally you are limited by floating point precision. For example, if you are using 64 bit floats:

```
fmax_64 = np.finfo(np.float64).max  # the largest representable 64 bit float
print(np.log(fmax_64))
# 709.782712893
```

If `x` is larger than about 709 then you simply won't be able to represent `np.exp(x)` (or  `1. / (1 + np.exp(x))`) using a 64 bit float.

You could use an extended precision float (i.e. `np.longdouble`):

```
fmax_long = np.finfo(np.longdouble).max
print(np.log(fmax_long))
# 11356.5234063
```

The precision of `np.longdouble` may vary depending on your platform - [on x86 it is usually 80 bit](http://mpmath.org/), which would allow you to work with `x` values up to about 11356:

```
func = lambda x: 1. / (1. + np.exp(np.longdouble(x)))
print(func(11356))
# 1.41861159972e-4932
```

Beyond that you would need to rethink how you're computing your expansion, or else use something like [mpmath](http://mpmath.org/) which supports arbitrary precision arithmetic. However this usually comes at the cost of much worse runtime performance compared with numpy, since vectorization is no longer possible.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at mpmath. I'll have to figure out what kind of precision will really be necessary for my task.

Comment: You might get a more helpful answer if you asked another question explaining the full problem you are trying to solve - maybe there is a way to avoid computing `exp(x)` altogether?